# Доступ к монаде IO из обработчика запросов Servant

Tags: маршрутизация, haskell

У меня есть 2 функции: updateGrid -> записывает JSON в файл

```
updateGrid :: Field -> IO ()
updateGrid f = I.writeFile "grids/field.json" (encodeToLazyText f)
```

и respond, который просто возвращает текст

```
respond :: Text
respond = pack "Success"
```

Мне нужно чтобы вызвалась функция updateGrid, а после её выполнения функция respond, чтобы в конечном итоге получить Text.

```
type ServerAPI =
        Get '[JSON] Text
   :<|> "new_game" :> Get '[JSON] Field
   :<|> "update_grid" :> ReqBody '[JSON] Field :> Post '[JSON] Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без текста программы не совсем понятно, но предположу, что обработчик должен выглядеть так.

```hs
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

updateGridHandler :: Field -> Handler Text
updateGridHandler field = do
  liftIO $ updateGrid field
  return respond
```

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо огромное!!